# Making Bitmap fit screen as Wallpaper

Tags: android, bitmap, wallpaper

I would like to set a bitmap as the androids wallpaper and I have that part figured out. However the image is always too big, off center and cropped. I have attempted to resize the bitmap to the display size but I still get the same result here is some of my code.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

final int maxWidth = display.getWidth();
final int maxHeight = display.getHeight();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(img_url).getContent());     


    int imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
if ( imageHeight > maxHeight )
imageHeight = maxHeight;
int imageWidth = (imageHeight*bitmap.getWidth()) / bitmap.getHeight();
if ( imageWidth > maxWidth ) {
imageWidth = maxWidth;
imageHeight = (imageWidth*bitmap.getHeight()) / bitmap.getWidth();
}


Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, imageWidth, imageHeight, true);

    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

Can anyone help me get the wallpaper image sized and centered correctly as the wallpaper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The wallpaper dimensions are acquired via [`WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDesiredMinimumHeight%28%29) and [`WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDesiredMinimumHeight%28%29). If either of these are `<= 0`, it requests the dimensions of the default display instead.

```
/* determine wallpaper dimensions */
final int w = myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
final int h = myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
final boolean need_w = w <= 0;
if (need_w || h <= 0) {
  final Rect rect = new Rect();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRectSize(rect);
  if (need_w) {
    w = rect.width();
  } else {
    h = rect.height();
  }
}

/* create resized bitmap */
final Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, false);
```

This doesn't preserve the aspect ratio, but  tell me how it goes.

Comment: Much closer. The width is off however, I read somewhere that it stretches the image to display across 3 screens or something?